# Configure storage report tab, file server resource manager (winapi)

Tags: powershell, winapi, fileserver

I need to migrate the configuration of a file server resource manager, I am using the [windows FSRM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658610(v=vs.85).aspx) to get and set the configurations.

In the file server configuration Options I have already found all the Classes for each tab, except the one contains the storage reports info.

My question is what is the class that manages the **storage reports tab** in the windows api.

.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "class"?

Comment: I am referring to the classes in programing, this are examples of one of the FSRm clases that I use 

**FsrmQuotaManager**
Used to manage quotas.
**FsrmQuotaTemplateManager**
Used to manage quota templates.
**FsrmReportManager**
Used to manage report jobs.

you can find all the fsrm clases in the following link 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the [PowerShell] tag in any way...?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the language the I am using to achieve this is powershell, I havent mentioned in the question it because I just need the class and all the documentation for the FSRM api is for C++.

Comment: Those classes are COM classes, and can be accessed by CLSID through interfaces accessed by IID. Does PowerShell have access to COM?

Comment: yes, you can acess COM clases in this way  `$fsrmQuotamanagerObj = new-object -com FSRM.FsrmQuotaManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the storage reports tab settings, using the winapi, in the properties of the server of the File Server resource manager you must use the method **[GetDefaultFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613312(v=vs.85).aspx)** of the class **[FsrmReportManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613309(v=vs.85).aspx)**

Here is a example of how to get it with powershell.

```
 $fsrmReportManagerObj = new-object -com FSRM.FsrmReportManager


#FileScreenAudit  
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(9,2)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(9,6)
#FilesByType(file group)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(2,5)
#FilesByOwner 
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(6,6)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(6,7)
#FilesByProperty
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(10,8)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(10,7)
#LargeFiles
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(1,1)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(1,7)
#LeastRecentlyAccessed
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(3,2)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(3,7)
#MostRecentlyAccessed
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(4,3)
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(4,7)
#QuotaUsage
$fsrmReportManagerObj.GetDefaultFilter(5)
```

If you want to set the storage reports tab settings, using the winapi, in the properties of the server of the File Server resource manager you must use the method **[SetDefaultFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613317(v=vs.85).aspx)** of the class **[FsrmReportManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613309(v=vs.85).aspx)**